# Changing the look of the Button Part Of A RadioButton Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have been looking on the net for some way to change the look of a basic radiobutton in silverlight. Say I want the actual button to have a blue border and a yellow background. And when its checked I want the little circle that fills in the radio button to be red. I wanna do this for the radio button on the windows phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article to do it in raw XAML:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093(v=vs.95).aspx

If you have Expression Blend, it can automatically generate the control's default XAML style for you to customize.   Right click on the element and click Edit Template | Edit a Copy...